# High CPU Utilization(~100%) while runing Tcl_DoOneEvent using LSF/bsub infrastructure

Tags: c, tcl, lsf

I have created my own event loop in Tcl as below. When i run the below code using tclsh interactively, CPU Utilization is close to 0% and when i run the same run using bsub, CPU Utilization shoots up to 100%.

I have even tried making read call blocking using below and that doesn't help too.

```
int flag = fcntl(0, F_GETFL);
flag = flag & (~O_NONBLOCK);
(void) fcntl(0, F_SETFL, (long)flag);
```

What is the reason here and how do i solve this problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <tcl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

void fwStdinKeyHandler(ClientData clientData, int mask)
{
  unsigned char c = 0;
  int rc = read(STDIN_FILENO, &c, 1);
  //printf("rc is : %d\n",rc);
  while (rc < 1 && errno == EINTR) {}
}


static void MainLoop(void)
{
  Tcl_CreateFileHandler(STDIN_FILENO, TCL_READABLE, fwStdinKeyHandler,    NULL);
  while (1) {
    Tcl_DoOneEvent(0);
  }
  fprintf(stdout,"Exit MainLoop\n");
  fflush(stdout);
}

static int Hello_Cmd(ClientData cdata, Tcl_Interp *interp, int objc, Tcl_Obj *const objv[])
{
  Tcl_SetMainLoop(MainLoop);
  return TCL_OK;
}

 /*
  * Hello_Init -- Called when Tcl loads your extension.
  */
int DLLEXPORT  Cmd_Init(Tcl_Interp *interp)
{
  if (Tcl_InitStubs(interp, TCL_VERSION, 0) == NULL) {
    return TCL_ERROR;
  }
  /* changed this to check for an error - GPS */
  if (Tcl_PkgProvide(interp, "Hello", "1.0") == TCL_ERROR) {
    return TCL_ERROR;
  }
  Tcl_CreateObjCommand(interp, "doone_loop", Hello_Cmd, NULL, NULL);
  return TCL_OK;
}
```

**How to make?**
1. File saved in,say, hello.c
2. gcc -fpic -c hello.c -I/usr/local/include
3. gcc -shared hello.o -o libcmd.so

**How to run?**
runme file contains:
*load libcmd.so

doone_loop*

/usr/bin/tclsh runme => CPU Utilization close to 0%
bsub -q interactive -m  "/usr/bin/tclsh runme" => CPU Utilization close to 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For non-interactive shell, there is no terminal and hence, no stdin channel, so read call returns zero. So, we need to add below code in fwStdinkeyhandler after read returns 0.

```
if(rc==0) {
   Tcl_DeleteFileHandler(0); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that when the command is run inside (the system that) `bsub` (talks to), it is run non-interactively. In particular, stdin is probably coming from either a file or `/dev/null`, both of which are *always* readable to the notifier (which is a tamed version of a bunch of low level system calls). That means your code is called back into a lot, almost as if it is busy-looping, generating a lot of CPU usage.

Since this is an operating system level behaviour, **your approach simply won't work.** You'll need to detect if you are in this situation (perhaps with `isatty()`?) and not install the event handler if it won't work right.

Comment: isatty() returns following for the below invocations:
usr/bin/tclsh runme => **1**
bsub -q interactive -m "/usr/bin/tclsh runme" => **0**
But i suspect whether isatty() can be used or not. Reason being there is one more bsub invocation where the interactive console comes to the shell from where you have given the bsub invocation. 
So, for invocation is: 
bsub -I -q interactive -m <host_name> "/usr/bin/tclsh bsub_run". => **0 is being returned**. CPU Utilization is nominal ~0% for this case, even though this is also a bsub invocation and isatty is 0.

What are your thoughts?